# Hive JDBC error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V7

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, impala, apache-hive

I'm trying to create a connection via JDBC to Impala using the Hive2 connector. But I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V7
      at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:175)
      at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
      at dsnoc.dsnoc_api.dolar.getDolarFromImpala(dolar.java:145)
      at dsnoc.dsnoc_api.dsnoc.main(dsnoc.java:75)
```

I don't know if it is a depencency compatibility issue:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

I'm using CDH 5.8.0 with Hive 1.1.0 and Hadoop 2.6.0

Or maybe is Code issue:

```
public static double getDolarFromImpala(String date)  {
    double dolar = 0.0;
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER_HIVE);
        String sql = "SELECT valor FROM dolar where fecha ='"+date+"'";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_HIVE2_URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()){
            dolar = rs.getDouble("valor");                                          
        }
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException se){
          //Handle errors for JDBC
          se.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
          //Handle errors for Class.forName
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dolar;
}
```

But I think is not, because I tried it with an Impala-JDBC and worked.

Other thing is that I'm not using the Impala-JDBC because it don't reads or sends the `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD`, throwing me this error:

```
 [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:AuthorizationException: User '' does not have privileges to execute 'SELECT'
```

Regards,

Comment: It sounds like you have a mismatch in dependencies.

Comment: If you want to connect to Impala, just use the Impala JDBC driver available on the Cloudera web site. Would you try a MySQL driver or an Oracle driver? No. So don't lose your time with the Apache Hive driver (which BTW has very limited support of JDBC features, does not work with older Hive server versions, etc. -- the Cloudera Hive driver is a better choice in many cases)

Comment: I'm using hive2 because Impala-JDBC don't reads the USERNAME and PASSWORD.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jars:

- hive-jdbc-2.1.1-standalone.jar
- hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar

depencency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

You can find this jars here: https://search.maven.org

This jars working for me in JMeter.